# NUL NUL NUL charachters after rewriting .PO file

Tags: php, function, transliteration

I am doing transliterate with basic php functions, when I finish the process I get plenty of NUL NUL NUL characters before text and translation. I tried something like this:

```
function transliterate($textcyr = "") {
    $lat = [
    'a','b','v','g','d','đ','e','ž','z','i','j','k','l','lj','m','n','nj','o','p','r','s','t','ć','u','f','h','c','č','dž','š','š','&scaron;',
    'A','B','V','G','D','Đ','E','Ž','Z','I','J','K','L','Lj','M','N','Nj','O','P','R','S','T','Ć','U','F','H','C','Č','Dž','Š','Š', '&Scaron;'
    ];
    
    $cyr = [
        'а','б','в','г','д','ђ','е','ж','з','и','ј','к','л','љ','м','н','њ','о','п','р','с','т','ћ','у','ф','х','ц','ч','џ','ш','ш',
        'А','Б','В','Г','Д','Ђ','Е','Ж','З','И','Ј','К','Л','Љ','М','Н','Њ','О','П','Р','С','Т','Ћ','У','Ф','Х','Ц','Ч','Џ','Ш','Ш'
    ];
    return str_replace($cyr, $lat, $textcyr);
}
    
function transliterate_po() {
    $filename = 'wp-content/languages/admin-sr_RS.po';
    $myFile = fopen($filename, "r+");
    if($myFile) {
        $textOriginal = fread($myFile,filesize($filename));
        $textTransliterated = transliterate($textOriginal);
        //var_dump($textOriginal);
        //echo '';
        //var_dump($textTransliterated);
        ftruncate($myFile, 0);
        fwrite($myFile, $textTransliterated);
        fclose($myFile);
        //var_dump('wp-content/languages/admin-sr_RS.po');
    } else {
        die("Unable to open file!");}
    }
```

I tried to change value of $textcyrl including null and I didn't get any result with this. Here is print screen [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kAHS.jpg)

Comment: Your translation function works correctly: https://onecompiler.com/php/3xxr62m7n

Comment: @Justinas Yes but when i compile PO file get 500 lines of NUL NUL NUL Characters. A cause of that i cant compile .mo file which is my next step. So i have to resolve this.

Comment: So maybe something else edits you file? Try using `file_get_contents`/`file_put_contents` and output to temporary file that is not `.po` file, then open it in text editor and check if there is still null bytes everywhere

Answer (score 0):

you'd better to generate them not editing them, However it's better to use `file_get_contents()` and then save another file and replace it with your `.po` file.

1- use `file_get_contents()`

2- replace via `transliterate`

3- save new file

but the best way is using these packages:

https://github.com/php-gettext/Gettext

https://github.com/raulferras/PHP-po-parser

https://code.google.com/archive/p/php-po-parser/

Comment: I am trying to evade parser, and not to make new files. This is how request is made.